# Indirect Object and neuter "lo" usage with inanimate objects

Tags: gramática, pronombres, objetos-indirectos, objetos-directos, clíticos

> Tenía a su lado el balón y le pegó una patada.

Why isn't *lo* used instead of *le* in this sentence? Doesn't *lo* refer to inanimate objects and *le* is used for animate objects? I think *le* refers to the ball.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Standard Spanish, there is generally no distinction made in animacy for the object pronouns<sup>1</sup>.  *Lo* and *la* are used for direct objects, being *lo* for masculine<sup>2</sup> and *la* for feminine.  *Le* is used for indirect objects<sup>3</sup> and represents the recipient of an action.

This sentence is a bit tricky, because the verb doesn't correlate in transivity to English.  Let's try rewriting it with some different words but the same structure to make it clearer:

> Tenía a su lado su novia y le dio un anillo.

What was given (direct object)?  *un anillo*. Whom was the ring given to?  The fiancée.

Likewise, in your sentence, what was given?<sup>4</sup>  *una patada*. Whom was the kick given to?  The ball.  The ball is thus an indirect object, and the only option in Standard Spanish for a singular, third-person, indirect object pronoun is *le*.

---

<sup>1.  The reality on the ground is that virtually every region within every country has its own tendencies on how to use *lo, la, le, los, las, les*.  Some of these *do* include animacy, others formality, and probably other things too.  Look up *laísmo*, *loísmo*, and *leísmo* for more information.</sup>
<sup>2.  Can also be neuter or attributive in some circumstances.</sup>
<sup>3.  *Le* is, however, accepted in Standard Spanish for masculine animate singular direct objects.  Plural use is not accepted, though quite common.</sup>
<sup>4.  Contextually, *pegar una patada* effectively means *to give a kick* here.</sup>

Comment: in short, the test for direct-object is "what?" and the test for indirect-objects is "to whom?"

Comment: @Drew yes, although the *what* can be a person, and the *to whom?* can be a thing (like in this case).

Answer (score 1):

The [answer from guifa](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/8621/1674) is very good.

Please notice that in several regions of Spain people uses this forms in the wrong way. It's a phenomena known as "leísmo" when they use *le* form instead of *lo/la* and "laísmo" when they use *lo/la* instead of *le*.

As far as I know, it does not happen on South America.

Comment: Leísmo definitely happens in some places in LA though lo/laísmo doesn't.  The most common pattern I've seen there is (as direct objects) *te=tú*, *lo=él/ello*, *la=ella*, and *le=Vd.* — and the RAE actually says this usage is acceptable.